# DoModal() problem, Windows XP vs Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a desktop application which is has been running for over 10 years under Windows XP.  The same .exe, when run under Windows 7, dies when the DoModal() call is executed.  Is there something different in this call now is Windows 7?  DoModal() never returns, so I can't test the return code.

Comment: what is the call stack at the time of hanging?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not hang, it just exits. - Dave Clark

Comment: What type of application do you have? Any modal dialog returns a value to its caller.

Comment: What's the output in the debugger? Any exception occuring? Any trace output?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this problem has not been answered for nearly two years.

I had the very same problem. I finally discovered that by reducing the Stack Reserve size and Stack Commit size settings in my project settings (linker:system) I was able to get doModal to work under windows-7.

My initial settings were 512 MB and 256 MB respectively. I reduced them to 64 MB and 32 MB and that made the app start working.

Comment: That looks weird that stack size changes the behavior. The root cause must lie somewhere else, and stack size somehow affects the execution. The OP hasn't answered the additional questions in comments, he/she isn't interested.